# Using a function to generate TF Learn DNN objects

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I'm working in a Jupyter notebook on trying to generate a long list of TF Learn DNN objects for some brute force trial and error testing (I know this isn't the most efficient method, just trying to show an example).  The data follows the Titanic quickstart tutorial.

I have a function that, given a bunch of parameters, should return a tflearn.DNN() objects:

```
def make_fully_connected(input_shape, output_shape, activation, layers, nodes, dropout, optimizer, loss):
    tflearn.init_graph()
    net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, input_shape])
    for l in range(layers):
        net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, nodes)
        if (dropout != 0) and (l%2==1):
            net = tflearn.dropout(net, dropout)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, output_shape, activation=activation)
    net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss)
    return tflearn.DNN(net)
```

Then I use that function to generate a specific model:

```
model = make_fully_connected(6, 2, 'softmax', 2, 32, 0, 'adam', 'categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(data, labels, n_epoch=10, batch_size=16, show_metric=True)
score = model.evaluate(data, labels)
```

But I get back a lovely error message that takes me into TF Learn code, and I get lost quickly:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-79e1d2acc8bf> in <module>()
      1 model = make_fully_connected(6, 2, 'softmax', 2, 32, 0, 'adam', 'categorical_crossentropy')
----> 2 model.fit(data, labels, n_epoch=10, batch_size=16, show_metric=True)
      3 score = model.evaluate(data, labels)
      4 print('| Score: %.4f' % score, end='')

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tflearn/models/dnn.py in fit(self, X_inputs, Y_targets, n_epoch, validation_set, show_metric, batch_size, shuffle, snapshot_epoch, snapshot_step, excl_trainops, validation_batch_size, run_id, callbacks)
    181         # TODO: check memory impact for large data and multiple optimizers
    182         feed_dict = feed_dict_builder(X_inputs, Y_targets, self.inputs,
--> 183                                       self.targets)
    184         feed_dicts = [feed_dict for i in self.train_ops]
    185         val_feed_dicts = None

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tflearn/utils.py in feed_dict_builder(X, Y, net_inputs, net_targets)
    287                 X = [X]
    288             for i, x in enumerate(X):
--> 289                 feed_dict[net_inputs[i]] = x
    290         else:
    291             # If a dict is provided

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is returning models from functions beyond the scope of TF Learn?  Or is there some other hurdle in the way?

Comment: what tf learn are you referring to?

Comment: tflearn 0.3; the version that installs via pip

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the kernel and clear output and to run it again . I too faced this issue and this solution worked for me . It is because you have run model multiple times and it had crashed .